# Как вывести в боте всевозможные записи пользователя из MySQL (python-telegram-bot)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот, python-telegram-bot

К телеграм боту на Python с библиотекой python-telegram-bot подключила БД MySQL.
У меня есть таблица `users`, где хранятся данные зарегистрированных пользователей.

**Пример таблицы users:**

```
+----+-----------+---------------+---------+-------+-----------------+------------------+
| id | user_name | record_number | user_id | phone |  types_massage  |    data_time     |
+----------------+---------------+---------+-------+-----------------+------------------+
| 1  | Marco     |  98542353     | 586512  | 98422 | Антицеллюлитный | 22/09/2020 12:00 |
| 2  | Oksi      |  78426565     | 548816  | 32145 | Медовый         | 19/09/2020 14:30 |
| 3  | Marco     |  49615862     | 866321  | 96374 | Лимфодренажный  | 09/09/2020 12:00 |
+----+-----------+---------------+---------+-------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Мне нужно вывести пользователю ВСЕ возможные его записи с условием выборки по имени.

Я делаю это так:

```
def st2_cancel_recording(update, context):
    mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
    sql = 'SELECT record_number, types_massage, data_time FROM Users WHERE user_name = %s'
    var = ('Marco', ) 
    mycursor.execute(sql, var)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        req = (' | '.join(x))
        print(' | '.join(x))

    update.message.reply_text('''_Ваши записи:_

*Номер* |      *Вид массажа*      | *Время приёма*
{req}'''.format(zayavka=zayavka), parse_mode='Markdown')
```

В консоли выводит всё правильно, первую и третью запись пользователя, но в самом телеграм боте показывает только третью (то есть последнюю) запись. **Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так? И как мне вывести в боте всевозможные записи?**

Comment: А можно увидеть полный текст кода. У меня вопрос похожий, но касается в плане вывода информации в бот из MSSQL БД. Сам механизм непонятен. Сделал выборку через EXEC, через for перебираю значения таблицы row, а как потом вывести в тг бот(telebot) не понимаю. Ткните пальцем где есть ответ?! [![мой код](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRFIn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRFIn.png) Первоначально задача такая: есть СКЛ БД, куда собирается информация температуры с датчиков, необходимо выводить температуру в ТГ бот каждые полчаса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в консоли так выводит потому что на каждой итерации вы выводите `print(' | '.join(x))`. А в телеграм бота отправляете последнее найденное значение.

Первое что пришло в голову это сделать так:

```
my_list = []
for x in myresult:
    my_list.append(' | '.join(x))
my_str = '\n'.join(my_list)
```

и потом в телеграм бота отправлять сразу `my_str`

Comment: Супер! Сработало. Спасибо огромное за помощь!)

Comment: @Julieta если ответ был полезен , слева можно нажать на стрелочку(ответ полезен) или галочку(чтобы ответ был помечен как решающий проблему)